# Why is there a large difference in CP between the Advantages Minion and Sidekick?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Why is there a large difference in CP between the Advantages Minion and Sidekick?

Sidekick = 5 CP/rank

Minion = 15 CP/rank

Shouldn't that be the other way around?s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minions follow the minion rules (worst result from failed Resistance checks, cannot critical hit non-minions, non-minions can attack with routine checks, etc.). See page 193 of the *Hero's Handbook* or the [Minions](http://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure#TOC-MINIONS) section of the SRD for the rules about minions:

> Minions are minor characters subject to special rules in combat, and generally easier to defeat than normal characters. Villains often employ hordes of minions against heroes. The following rules apply to minions:
>
> Minions cannot score critical hits against non-minions.
>
> Non-minions can make attack checks against minions as routine checks.
>
> If a minion fails a resistance check, the minion suffers the worst degree of the effect. So a minion failing a Damage resistance check, for example, is incapacitated, regardless of the degree of failure.
>
> Certain traits (like the Takedown advantage) are more effective against or specifically target minions.

An additional wrinkle in there, mentioned in the section on [critical hits](http://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure/#TOC-INCREASED-THREAT-RANGE):

> **Increased Effect**: The critical hit increases the difficulty to resist the attack’s effect by +5. Against a minion, this bypasses the resistance check entirely; the minion automatically receives the highest degree of the attack’s effect.

Since [minions aren't replaced until between adventures](http://www.d20herosrd.com/5-advantages#TOC-MINION-GENERAL-RANKED-) (and a GM might introduce Complications preventing replacement if a hero is too cavalier with his minions), that fragility can be very vexing.

> Any lost minions are replaced in between adventures with other followers with similar abilities at the Gamemaster’s discretion.

Sidekicks are full characters, following all the same rules as a player character except for having Hero Points (although the hero can spend Hero Points for their behalf).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79756/discussion-on-answer-by-valhallagh-why-is-there-a-large-difference-in-cp-between).

Answer (score 3):

*Hey I Can Chan* raised an excellent point in his comment that the question could also indicate a confusion about the cost of Sidekicks and Minions versus their benefits.

> @SeanDuggan The recent edit—to this outsider, anyway—doesn't seem to clarify the core issue. That is, a sidekick being a full character seems to be an advantage, while a minion being… well… a minion seems to be a disadvantage… yet a minion still costs more per rank than a sidekick (when it sounds like a minion should cost less). Can this answer address this discrepancy? (My only takeaway from this so far is that because a sidekick is a full character—therefore irreplaceable (unless its Robin)—that a sidekick costs less, and that still seems off, especially in the short run.) – Hey I Can Chan *2018-July-4-10:17 AM EST*

Both the [Minion](http://www.d20herosrd.com/5-advantages#TOC-MINION-GENERAL-RANKED-) and [Sidekick](http://www.d20herosrd.com/5-advantages#TOC-SIDEKICK-GENERAL-RANKED-) advantages cost 1 PP per rank (SRD text will instead refer to "CP" due to trademark issues). Minions get 15 PP per rank of the Minion Advantage to spend in their creation. Sidekicks get 5 PP per rank in the Sidekick Advantage. The reason for this discrepancy is that, as covered in [ValhallaGH's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125621/10867), Sidekicks are significantly more durable.