# Trying to make a Familiar like D&D 3.5e for a Magical Boy in M&M3e

Tags: familiars, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm playing a magical boy or better version of Tuxedo Mask. I want to emulate what D&D 3.5e [Familiars](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm#familiars) can do. Would a Power or an Advantage be better to do so? Minion, Summon, or Sidekick? How do I emulate the ability for my Familiar to be able to cast the spells I can as long as they are within 60 feet from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either Sidekick or Minion if your Familiar is always with you. Sidekick is best if you want to avoid them dying quickly as per the top-ranked answer at [Why is there a large difference in CP between the Advantages Minion and Sidekick?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125620/why-is-there-a-large-difference-in-cp-between-the-advantages-minion-and-sidekick) although it will make them more expensive.

To let them use your powers, you basically have them buy those powers, with a [Limited](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-LIMITED--1-COST-PER-RANK-) Flaw that they can only use them when within 60 feet of you (your GM might decide this is more of a Quirk if this will prevent it less than half the time). This will let them use that power as their action.

Alternately, that could be a good case for the [Indirect](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-INDIRECT-FLAT-1-4-POINTS-) Flat Extra. Three ranks should nicely handle "From nearly any point, any direction your Familiar is facing" (Honestly, it's sort of an Indirect 4 (any point, any direction) with a Quirk of "Originates from my familiar"). This has the drawback that it's your action to fire off the power.

Seeing through the familiar is [Remote Sensing](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/remote-sensing-sensory) with a Medium (Familiar) Flaw. Communicating with them is the [Communication Link from Senses](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/senses-sensory#TOC-COMMUNICATION-LINK-1-RANK).